# getimagesize() failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! error

Tags: php, http, request, getimagesize

I'm using wordpress in my blog, but I see repeated errors in error_log as below. How can I solve this problem?

Thanks.

error_log

```
[29-Nov-2015 12:01:14 UTC] PHP Warning:  getimagesize(http://hardal.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/glogo.png): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!  in /home/hardal/public_html/wp-content/themes/hardal/header.php on line 36
[29-Nov-2015 12:01:14 UTC] PHP Warning:  getimagesize(http://hardal.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/glogo21.png): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!  in /home/hardal/public_html/wp-content/themes/hardal/functions/theme-actions.php on line 38
```

theme-actions.php line 36 to 41

```
  <div class="row" id="copyright-note">
<?php if ($albay_options['albay_footer_logo'] != '') { ?>
    <?php list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($albay_options['albay_footer_logo']); ?>
    <div class="foot-logo">
        <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" rel="nofollow"><img src="<?php echo $albay_options['albay_footer_logo']; ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>" <?php echo $attr; ?>></a>
    </div>
```

header.php line 33 to 43

```
                <?php if ($albay_options['albay_logo'] != '') { ?>
                <?php if( is_front_page() || is_home() || is_404() ) { ?>
                        <h1 id="logo" class="image-logo">
                            <?php list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($albay_options['albay_logo']); ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $albay_options['albay_logo']; ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>" <?php echo $attr; ?>></a>
                        </h1><!-- END h1-->
                <?php } else { ?>
                      <h2 id="logo" class="image-logo">
                            <?php list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($albay_options['albay_logo']); ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $albay_options['albay_logo']; ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>" <?php echo $attr; ?>></a>
                        </h2><!-- END h2-->
```

Comment: Seems to me that is can't find the file.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I solve this problem?

Well, seems you need to do more test about it for making sure what's the problem before start solving it.

The `error_log` provided you some clues to let you know that is the `getimagesize` function had a problem about `HTTP request` when handling `http://hardal.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/glogo.png` and another URL.

Because of this is linked to `HTTP request`, to found out what exactly the error is, you may need `$http_response_header` variable.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php

> The $http_response_header array is similar to the get_headers() function. When using the HTTP wrapper, $http_response_header will be populated with the HTTP response headers. $http_response_header will be created in the local scope.

Notice this variable only available when the `HTTP wrapper` is successfully connected to a HTTP server and that server did respond. If it's not a HTTP server or connection has failed, the `$http_response_header` will be empty or not be set.

So, for debug (Or cause seeking) purpose, you can make some code like this:

```
getimagesize('http://hardal.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/glogo.png');

if (empty($http_response_header)) {
    exit('Connection failed.');
}

// See if the response string contains `200`. works in `HTTP/1.1` at least
if (strpos($http_response_header[0], '200') === false) {
    exit('HTTP Error: ' . $http_response_header[0]);
}
```

Run it, this will prints out more detailed error information. Then:

- If it said "Connection failed", check your port, firewall related stuffs.
- If it said "HTTP Error: blablabla", check your target (hardal.com) HTTP server's setting.

Notice: Remember to remove above debug-purposed code before back to production.